# Shuffle between subnets from two terraform maps as input for ec2 instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have two sets of CIDRs for each environment, i would like for terraform to shuffle between the two sets whenever a new instance is being created.

I have looked at the terraform `random_shuffle` provider and the merge function but these do not provide the solution to my problem.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "myapp" {
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr[terraform.workspace], 5, count.index + 16 + 5)}"
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    QA   = "20.30.100.0/23"
    TEST = "20.37.200.0/23"
    PROD = "20.37.200.0/23"
    DEV  = "20.37.100.0/23"
  }
}

locals {
  "vpc_cidr_2" = {
    QA   = "10.30.182.0/23"
    TEST = "10.37.238.0/23"
    PROD = "<none>"
    DEV  = "<none>"
  }
}
```

I would like cidr_block to be calculated based on either vpc_cidr or vpc_cidr2 and shuffle between each. Also it would need to check for  and fall back to the other map if  is found.

> Note: `vpc_cidr` is a variable while `vpc_cidr_2` is a local.

Answer (score 0):

`random_shuffle` is the right resource you should work on, but you need change the idea to mix variable and locals together.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "myapp" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(lookup(var.vpc_cidr[random_shuffle.vpc_cidr.result], terraform.workspace), 5, count.index + 16 + 5)}"
}

resource "random_shuffle" "vpc_cidr" {
  input = ["vpc_cidr", "vpc_cidr_2"]
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    vpc_cidr = {
      "QA"   = "20.30.100.0/23"
      "TEST" = "20.37.200.0/23"
      "PROD" = "20.37.200.0/23"
      "DEV"  = "20.37.100.0/23"
    }

    vpc_cidr_2 = {
      "QA"   = "10.30.182.0/23"
      "TEST" = "10.37.238.0/23"
      "PROD" = "<none>"
      "DEV"  = "<none>"
    }
  }
}
```